# Connection requests hang with SYN_SENT, after a few tries

Tags: networking, ssh

We moved offices, and setup the LAN/WAN infrastructure at the new place.

When I initiate SSH connections to my server (which is in the cloud, not the LAN), it works OK for the first 3 or 4 requests at short intervals (like 4 calls within 5 secs), further connections hang in SYN_SENT status. Later requests all hang with SYN_SENT until what looks like a timeout. After that it will work again for a few times.

No changes were made to the server and different local clients behave this way. So I guess the difference lies in the IT infrastructure, not the two end-points.

What possible explanations are there for this behavior? Where should I look for a fix?

We use a Zyxel ZyWall firewall which we had to reset - does this have some filter which could explain this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The iptables rules on the server had a an "anti ssh bruteforce" rule chain which uses the "recent" module to drop connections after 4 attempts were made within 1 minute. 
This rule had an exception in the `INPUT` chain, to allow all ssh from our face IP. As we moved, the face IP changed, and the rule had to be adapted. For reference, this is how I did this

List all iptables rules

```
# iptables -L --line-numbers
```

Notice the accept rule in the `INPUT` chain, which was set to accept all ssh connections from our (previous) face IP address and the anti bruteforce rule which drops ssh connections after several attempts in the `SSH_CHECK` chain:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
...
14   ACCEPT     tcp  --  old.myISP.com      anywhere tcp dpt:ssh
...
Chain SSH_CHECK (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
...
3    DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            recent: UPDATE seconds: 60 hit_count: 4 TTL-Match name: RECENT_SSH side: source
```

Editing the rules in `/etc/iptables.rules`

Change

```
-A INPUT -s 123.45.67.8/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

to

```
-A INPUT -s 111.222.33.44 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

where 111.222.33.44 is the new face IP.
And read in the adapted rules:

```
 # iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
```